# C++ array of strings terminator

Tags: c++, arrays, null, c-strings, string-literals

I am new to C++, I know that character arrays/char*(c-strings) terminate with a Null byte, but is it the same for string arrays/char**?

My main question is: how can i know if I reached the end of a char** variable? Will the following code work?

```
#include <cstddef>

char** myArray={"Hello", "World"};

for(char** str = myArray; *str != NULL; str++) {
  //do Something
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For starters this declaration

```
char** myArray={"Hello", "World"};
```

does not make a sense, You may not initialize a scalar object with a braced-list with more than one expression.

It seems you mean a declaration of an array

```
const char* myArray[] ={ "Hello", "World"};
```

In this case the for loop can look like

```
for( const char** str = myArray; *str != NULL; str++) {
  //do Something
}
```

But the array does not have an element with a sentinel value. So this condition in the for loop

```
*str != NULL
```

results in undefined behavior.

You could rewrite the loop for example like

```
for( const char** str = myArray; str != myArray + sizeof( myArray ) / sizeof( *myArray ); str++) {
  //do Something
}
```

Or instead of the expression with the `sizeof` operator you could use the standard function `std::size` introduced in the C++ 17 Standard.

Otherwise the initial loop would be correct if the array is declared like

```
const char* myArray[] ={ "Hello", "World", nullptr };
```

In this case the third element will satisfy the condition of the loop.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, would sizeof or std::size work inside a function? I heard that when you pass the variable in a function the sizeof doesn't work, is that correct?

Comment: @PTorPro If you will pass the array by reference then it will work. Otherwise the array designator will be converted to a pointer to its first element. In this case you need also to pass the number of elements in the array. Or append the array with the sentinel value nullptr. as it was already pointed.

Answer (score 3):

You need to terminate it:

```
const char** myArray={"Hello", "World", nullptr};
```

As you should be using `nullptr` in C++, not `NULL` which is for C code.

Additionally, **use `std::vector` and `std::string`** instead of this mess:

```cpp
std::vector<std::string> myArray = { "Hello", "World" };

for (auto&& str : myArray) {
  // ... str is your string reference
}
```

Comment: `std::array` is better adapted for this than `std::vector`.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Why? It's an academic distinction. 99% of the time `std::vector` is totally fine. This isn't performance critical code, and it's not hitting any memory limits.

Comment: The size is compile-time constant. `std::vector` adds a dynamic allocation and size mutability.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Premature optimization. Yes, technically you can use `std::array` but it's not necessary, and it provides nearly zero gain here. Sometimes you want mutability. Sometimes you don't. `std::vector` really doesn't care one way or the other. `std::array` is for a subset of cases where you need those things you're talking about, which isn't the case in a trivial bit of code like this.

Comment: It isn't any more premature optimization than using const reference arguments to avoid copies. This is using the tool for the job it was designed for... `std::array` better expresses the intent.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux For someone learning C++ it's a lot better to say "Use `std::vector` as a starting point" than to say "Use this other thing which has better copy semantics and other stuff you won't understand but I'll bring up now for no reason other than to confuse the situation." We can get extremely pedantic here. *Please don't.*

Comment: There are a lot of thing in that "quote" that don't reflect anything I said, or propose saying. I don't think `std::vector` is wrong here, and I accordingly didn't downvote. But `std::array` is a simple improvement that I would have thought would be uncontroversial. I agree that it may be best to limit the number of containers a beginner should be exposed to, but `std::array` doesn't seem so complex or arcane that it is something that beginners should be shielded from. But this is your answer, use what you want.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I'm not saying "don't use `std::array`". I'm saying in this specific context it makes sense to introduce a generic, widely applicable tool first. Given a choice between `std::array` and `std::vector` I'm going with the latter, once understood it can solve a lot of problems. The former not so much.